# What is the constraint error i am getting here in my asp.net c# code? i think it is some data table grid related problem but im unable to solve it

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkH17.png)
Error message on my .xsd file
It says one more row contain the  values violating not null, unique or foreign key constraints

Answer (score 0):

When encountering this kind of problem, my general solution is to put the SQL statements generated by the software into the database for execution, and then see if there is any problem.

Comment: It might be interesting to specify where or how to see the "generated SQL statement". ex. say SQL Profiler